# Can't get the coefficient of a particular solution for a Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a differential equation that goes as follows:
$$y'' - \left( a + 1 \right) \cdot y' + a \cdot y = 2 \cdot \cosh(a \cdot x),\, a \in \mathbb{R}$$
I have progressed enough and now trying to get the particular solution for $e^{ax}$, using the form $y_p = Ae^{ax}$. The problem is that putting it in the equation gives $0 = e^{ax}$, making me unable to get $A$ to begin with. I suspect that I've done something wrong along the road but can't determine it. I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: What are your two homogeneous solutions? And  why did you assume the particular solution would be of the form $Ae^{ax}$?

Comment: $2cosh(ax) = e^{ax} + e^{-ax}$, so I separated each case and used that form to get the values of A and B

Comment: Hint: a particular solution can't be a homogeneous solution (basically because $A \cdot 0$ is $0$ no matter what $A$ is), so if $e^{ax}$ is a homogeneous solution then you'll need to try something else. You have probably encountered an explanation of what to do in this situation already.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the hint: $(y'' - (a + 1)y' + ay)=(y''-ay'-y'+ay)=((y'-y)'-a(y'-y))$. You can try the substitution as $u=(y'-y)$.